# How do I hide .dropbox Files?

Tags: dropbox

I have a bunch of these files automatically produced by Dropbox and I'd love to hide them:

[image]

Any ideas on the best way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
attrib +h .dropbox /s
```

Dropbox usually marks these files as hidden automatically.

You might also want to look whether your Windows Explorer is configured to hide [hidden files](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-vista/Show-hidden-files).

Comment: Mine are hidden already as well.

Comment: Pretty simple solution, I've just removed it several times. Have not noticed anything weird afterwards. Still would like to know does this file appear normally in the first place or is it because of some confusion between the Windows client and e.g. Dropsync client on Android? As known, dot means hidden file on Linux systems...